# Irfanview for OSX ML (10.8.4)

Tags: macos, imagemagick, osx-mountain-lion, x11

Wondering if anyone else is successfully using irfanview on OSX ML?
Or if you might suggest an alternative - a quick-n-easy image viewer with similar browsing features. (sry, iphoto and preview just seem to lack the features I miss from irfanview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found! (for me at least)

- feh

Used Homebrew to install it. (Thanks Homebrew!)

On OSX.ML, this requires X11 install too (used XQuartz 2.7.4 which i had installed anyway).

I'm a unix / terminal / command line user so 'feh' works very well for me.
Unfortunately doesn't handle webp naturally yet (probably only a matter of time tho). But I can use Chrome for view those images in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution using WineBottler [edited for recent versions and Mountain Lion].

Technically it works - irfanview does install on OSX.ML. And irfanview can read many file formats just fine. But it appears to be limited to 'built-in' formats and has problems loading images which use one of its plugins.

The Z: directory maps to the mac root. Once I figured that out it made more sense. Also, it is a bit clunky to use and not quite as convenient as it is on Windows. (Sort of sad. Well, I will just keep looking!)

--

Try WineBottler

This free software is a wrapper for WINE, which unlike other Windows emulators is really simple to set up.
It just works.

```
1 download WineBottler and install it. I used the developer version of wine-bottler (does not need X11 which OSX.ML no longer has by default)
2 Download the latest version of IrfanView (4.36)
3 Start WineBottler and Create a Custom Prefix
4 For the Install File, select the IrfanView installation file you just downloaded
5 In the Winetricks section select vcrun6
6 Click Install
```

You'll then see a standard Windows installation - follow the prompts.

At the end there's a pop-up, from which you should select ivew32.exe as the executable to run. (it defaulted to the slideshow for me)

That's it! WineBottler generates an Irfanview App that can by launched like any Mac App.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth checking out PicTwiddle Lite - only supports the most common image formats, but it wasn't clear from your question what you need. Similar browsing to IrfanView though, plus you can browse folders/thumbnails in fullscreen which is nice. And it has an OSX version.

You have to scroll down to the bottom of the page for the Lite/Free version: http://pictwiddle.com/download/